# SwiftUI + Firestore - Filter List based on array returned from Firestore

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I'm trying to take the results of a Firestore subcollection query and then filter a list of items based on the results of the query.

I'm able to successfully query and print to console my Firestore query, however, I'm a little lost on how to set the results of the query to an array in which I can filter my list.

Printing the value of favoriteID in my function shows:

"[163, 169]"

I'm struggling with how to append that array in the "self.data.append..." and then filtering the list in my view based on the value of "data".

Here's my current code. It currently just displays all items from my data model. I'd like it to filter and only show items with matching Product ID's.

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore

struct FavoritesView: View {
@EnvironmentObject var session: SessionStore
@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
@State var data: [FavoritesStore] = []

var model = Passport.all()
let db = Firestore.firestore()

func getFavorites() {
    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid ?? "nil"

    if (session.session != nil) {
        self.data.removeAll()
        db.collection("users").document(userID).getDocument { (document, error) in
            if let document = document, document.exists {
                let favoriteID = document.get("favorites") as! Array<Int>
               print(favoriteID as Any)
            //  self.data.append(FavoritesStore(favorites: favoriteID) as! Array<Any>)
           //     print(self.data)
                } else {
                    print("Document does not exist")
                    }
                }
        }
}

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        VStack {
            List {
                ForEach(self.model) { venues in
                    ForEach(venues.venues) { items in
                        ForEach(items.venueItems) { item in
                            VStack {
                                Text(item.title)
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
            .navigationBarTitle(Text(""))
            .resignKeyboardOnDragGesture()
            .background(Color("bodyBackground"))
            .onAppear(perform: getFavorites)
        }
        VStack {
            GeometryReader { gr in
                HStack {
                    Button(action: {self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()}) {
                        Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                            .padding(.leading, 16)
                        HStack {
                            Text("Explore · Favorites")
                                .font(.system(size: 15))
                                .fontWeight(.bold)
                                .foregroundColor(Color.black)

                                .padding()
                            Spacer()
                        }
                    }.frame(width: gr.size.width * 0.92, height: 48)
                        .background(Color.white)
                        .cornerRadius(8)
                        .shadow(color: Color("Shadow"), radius: 10, x: 2, y: 7)
                }.padding(.leading, 16)
                Spacer()
            }
        }
        .padding(.top, 50)
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)

        }
    }
}

class FavoritesStore: ObservableObject {
    @Published var favorites: [Favorite]

init (favorites: [Favorite]) {
    self.favorites = favorites
    }
}


class Favorite: ObservableObject {
    var id: Int

    init(id: Int) {
        self.id = id
        }
}
```

Passport Model

```
Passport (
            id: 1001,
            passportPremium: false,
            passportActive: true,
            passportTitle : "Festival of the Holidays",
            passportDescription: "An International Yuletide Extravaganza Savor seasonal food & beverage specialties at the expanded Holiday Kitchens. And take a festive global tour—as costumed performers bring time-honored traditions to life throughout World Showcase!",
            passportDates: "Nov. 29 - Dec. 30, 2019",
            passportYear: "2019",
            passportImage: "Event-Festival-Holidays",
            passportImageVert: "Event-Festival-Holidays-Vert",
            venues: [
                Venue (
                    title: "Bavaria Holiday Kitchen",
                    venueImage: "defaultVenue",
                    venueDesc: "ipsum lorem",
                    venueArea: "World Showcase East",
                    coordinate: .init(latitude: -33.852222, longitude: 151.210556),
                    venueItems: [
                        venueItem (
                            id: 101,
                            title: "Potato Dumpling",
                            itemURL: "https://www.example.com/app/wdw-default.png",
                            productDescription: "Potato Dumpling with Mushroom Sauce",
                            productPrice: 4.50,
                            productType: "Food",
                            newStatus: false,
                            diningPlan: false,
                            kidFriendly: true,
                            vegetarian: false,
                            glutenFree: false,
                            featuredProduct: false,
                            containsAlcohol: false
                        ),
                        venueItem (
                            id: 102,
                            title: "Pork Schnitzel",
                            itemURL: "https://www.example.com/app/wdw-default.png",
                            productDescription: "Pork Schnitzel with Mushroom Sauce and Spaetzle",
                            productPrice: 6.25,
                            productType: "Food",
                            newStatus: true,
                            diningPlan: false,
                            kidFriendly: false,
                            vegetarian: false,
                            glutenFree: false,
                            featuredProduct: false,
                            containsAlcohol: false
                        ),
                        venueItem (
                            id: 103,
                            title: "Cheese Fondue",
                            itemURL: "https://www.example.com/app/wdw-default.png",
                            productDescription: "Cheese Fondue in a Bread Bowl with Fresh Steamed Baby Vegetables and Marble Potatoes",
                            productPrice: 8.25,
                            productType: "Food",
                            newStatus: false,
                            diningPlan: false,
                            kidFriendly: true,
                            vegetarian: false,
                            glutenFree: false,
                            featuredProduct: false,
                            containsAlcohol: false
                        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly you can try something like this

```
    for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
          print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
          let favoriteID = document.data("productID") as Int
          if let row = self.model.firstIndex(where: { $0.productID != favoriteID  }) {
              self.model.remove(at: row)
          } 
    }
```

Comment: I updated the question with the data model. The only issue I'm having now is with the "if let row = " syntax since the productID is nested. ProductID would refer to the "id" on "venueItem"

Comment: Can you elaborate what the problem is with the ProductID?